# How to append text to normalized stacked chart in d3js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to append text to a normalized stacked chart in *d3js v4*, similarly to [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/vDG2sgiQBdDE52NAJRoG?p=preview)

but with the values of the correspondent bars showing inside the bars.

Here's the code from the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .bar {
    fill: steelblue;
  }

  .axis path {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="870"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 60,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 40
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.1)
    .align(0.1);

  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

  var stack = d3.stack()
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand);

  d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    data.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b[data.columns[1]] / b.total - a[data.columns[1]] / a.total;
    });

    y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
      return d.State;
    }));
    z.domain(data.columns.slice(1));

    var serie = g.selectAll(".serie")
      .data(stack.keys(data.columns.slice(1))(data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "serie")
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return z(d.key);
      });

    serie.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.data.State);
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]) - x(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10, "%"));

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    var legend = serie.append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var d = d[0];
        return "translate(" +  ((x(d[0]) + x(d[1])) / 2) + ", " +(y(d.data.State) - y.bandwidth())+ ")";
      });

    legend.append("line")
      .attr("y1", 5)
      .attr("x1", 15)
      .attr("x2", 15)
      .attr("y2", 12)
      .attr("stroke", "#000");

    legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key;
      });
  });

  function type(d, i, columns) {
    for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
    d.total = t;
    return d;
  }
</script>
```

And here's the dataset(csv):

```
State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years,18 to 24 Years,25 to 44 Years,45 to 64 Years,65 Years and Over
AL,310504,552339,259034,450818,1231572,1215966,641667
AK,52083,85640,42153,74257,198724,183159,50277
AZ,515910,828669,362642,601943,1804762,1523681,862573
AR,202070,343207,157204,264160,754420,727124,407205
CA,2704659,4499890,2159981,3853788,10604510,8819342,4114496
CO,358280,587154,261701,466194,1464939,1290094,511094
CT,211637,403658,196918,325110,916955,968967,478007
DE,59319,99496,47414,84464,230183,230528,121688
DC,36352,50439,25225,75569,193557,140043,70648
FL,1140516,1938695,925060,1607297,4782119,4746856,3187797
GA,740521,1250460,557860,919876,2846985,2389018,981024
HI,87207,134025,64011,124834,356237,331817,190067
ID,121746,201192,89702,147606,406247,375173,182150
IL,894368,1558919,725973,1311479,3596343,3239173,1575308
IN,443089,780199,361393,605863,1724528,1647881,813839
IA,201321,345409,165883,306398,750505,788485,444554
KS,202529,342134,155822,293114,728166,713663,366706
KY,284601,493536,229927,381394,1179637,1134283,565867
LA,310716,542341,254916,471275,1162463,1128771,540314
ME,71459,133656,69752,112682,331809,397911,199187
MD,371787,651923,316873,543470,1556225,1513754,679565
MA,383568,701752,341713,665879,1782449,1751508,871098
MI,625526,1179503,585169,974480,2628322,2706100,1304322
MN,358471,606802,289371,507289,1416063,1391878,650519
MS,220813,371502,174405,305964,764203,730133,371598
MO,399450,690476,331543,560463,1569626,1554812,805235
MT,61114,106088,53156,95232,236297,278241,137312
NE,132092,215265,99638,186657,457177,451756,240847
NV,199175,325650,142976,212379,769913,653357,296717
NH,75297,144235,73826,119114,345109,388250,169978
NJ,557421,1011656,478505,769321,2379649,2335168,1150941
NM,148323,241326,112801,203097,517154,501604,260051
NY,1208495,2141490,1058031,1999120,5355235,5120254,2607672
NC,652823,1097890,492964,883397,2575603,2380685,1139052
ND,41896,67358,33794,82629,154913,166615,94276
OH,743750,1340492,646135,1081734,3019147,3083815,1570837
OK,266547,438926,200562,369916,957085,918688,490637
OR,243483,424167,199925,338162,1044056,1036269,503998
PA,737462,1345341,679201,1203944,3157759,3414001,1910571
RI,60934,111408,56198,114502,277779,282321,147646
SC,303024,517803,245400,438147,1193112,1186019,596295
SD,58566,94438,45305,82869,196738,210178,116100
TN,416334,725948,336312,550612,1719433,1646623,819626
TX,2027307,3277946,1420518,2454721,7017731,5656528,2472223
UT,268916,413034,167685,329585,772024,538978,246202
VT,32635,62538,33757,61679,155419,188593,86649
VA,522672,887525,413004,768475,2203286,2033550,940577
WA,433119,750274,357782,610378,1850983,1762811,783877
WV,105435,189649,91074,157989,470749,514505,285067
WI,362277,640286,311849,553914,1487457,1522038,750146
WY,38253,60890,29314,53980,137338,147279,65614
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
var textAndRect = serie.selectAll("g")
  .data(function(d) {
    d.forEach(function(d0){
      d0.key = d.key;
    })
    return d;
  })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d){
    return "translate(" + [x(d[1]), y(d.data.State)]  + ")";
  })

textAndRect.append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d[0]) - x(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

textAndRect.append("text")
  .text(function(d){
    return d.data[d.key];
  })
  .attr("x", function(d){
    return (x(d[0]) - x(d[1])) / 2;
  })
  .attr("dy", "1.1em")
  .style("font-family","arial")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .style("font-size", "7pt")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

Running code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ARY2CDIOZCza0W8pL81?p=preview).